# TF2 Resistance Sound Cue

Tags: team-fortress-2

I've been looking through the audio files of Team Fortress 2 but I am unable to find the sound that plays when using the Vaccinator and the resistance type matches oncoming damage. The sound also plays in MvM when any damage resistance has been bought and relevant damage is taken. Any help would be appreciated. In the meantime I'll recheck the sound files to see if I might have missed it.

Comment: Have you tried extracting all the files from the sound vpk cache? Should be in there.

Comment: @memescientist Not knowing the filename of it isn't that useful.  It's not listed in [`scripts/game_sounds_weapons.txt`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/powerlord/tf2-data/master/game_sounds/game_sounds_weapons.txt) like you'd think either.  Or at least not under an obvious name or grouped with the other Vaccinator sounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running the game with `developer 1`, quitting a server will show you a list of all the sounds running at the time you quit (as a list of "the sounds that were cut off"). So, I went to an MvM map, got some resistance upgrades, use `host_timescale 0.2` to time things easier, and quit the server just as the resistance sound was playing from a rocket jump. It listed these sounds:

> `0:Stopped sound )weapons\doom_rocket_launcher.wav`
>
> `2:Stopped sound )weapons\samurai\tf_katana_impact_object_02.wav`
>
> `3:Stopped sound vo\soldier_painsevere05.wav`
>
> `4:Stopped sound ui\buttonclick.wav`
>
> `5:Stopped sound ui\buttonclickrelease.wav`

(Dunno why there's no sound with index 1).

So, here's what it gives:

1. `doom_rocket_launcher` is the Beggar's Bazooka, which I was using.
2. `soldier_painsevere05` is just the Soldier going "aggh" or whatever.
3. The two `ui\` sounds are from the act of clicking the "disconnect" button (and, as it's an MvM map, the subsequent "yes I want to quit" box).
4. That leaves `weapons\samurai\tf_katana_impact_object_02.wav`.

Going into the VPK and opening up `weapons\samurai\tf_katana_impact_object_02.wav`: yes indeed, that sounds like the resistance sound to me. Maybe it randomly picks between _01, _02, and _03, but I think we found the sound used for resistances.